# Создание штрих-кода и его печать C#

Tags: c#, .net, поиск-библиотек, штрихкод, barcode

Я получаю из БД данные, содержащие уникальные поля. Мне нужно создать штрих-код для выбранного элемента по уникальному полю в формате code-128 и сразу же вывести диалоговое окна сохранить/распечатать. Вопрос в следующем, как в C# программно можно создать картинку штрих-код в формате code-128 и предложить его сохранить как картинку или вывести на печать? Какие NuGet-пакеты есть для этой цели или же можно обойтись без их использования?

Comment: Попробуйте это http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741346/free-barcode-128-library-for-c-sharp

Comment: Посмотрите, может быть в этом списке найдется пакет для генерации штрих-кодов, который Вам подойдет https://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/barcode. Чтобы понять, как вывести штрих-код на печать надо понимать, что за приложение у Вас (десктоп, веб...)

Comment: @SerafimProzorov у меня wpf desctop приложение. Библиотеку нашел, получилось закодировать и сохранить. Подскажите как вызвать окно для печати с выбором принтера?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использовал nuget пакет [**BarcodeLib**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BarcodeLib/). Он легок в использовании и кодирует в нужный мне формат. Пример использования вместе с сохранением в PDF файл с помощью библиотеки [**iTextSharp**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/):

```
private void OnSaveSelectedCells()
{
    var barcode = new BarcodeLib.Barcode();

    var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog { FileName = "Barcodes", Filter = "PDF file (*.pdf)|*.pdf" };

    if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        var document = new Document();

        var fileStream = new FileStream(saveFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);

        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fileStream);

        // Для отображения русских букв
        var baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\Arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
        var font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(baseFont, 14);

        document.Open();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var imageBarcode = barcode.Encode(BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE128B, item.Barcode, Color.Black, Color.White, 290, 120);

            var image = Image.GetInstance(imageBarcode, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            document.Add(new Paragraph(item.Description, font));
            document.Add(image);
        }

        document.Close();
        // Открытие созданного файла
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(saveFileDialog.FileName);
    }
}
```